# C split array of strings to subarrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

I am doing a shell (in C) for school assignment and I have this problem: I have read the input and have array of words. (like this: {"/bin/ls", "-l", ">", "file"}) And I want to have subarrays with all words between special symbols like '<', '>', '|'. So if my input is

```
/bin/ls -l > f.txt > /usr/bin/wc
```

I want to have:

```
{{"bin/ls", "-l"}, {"f.txt"}, {"usr/bin/wc"}}
```

So that I can easily call execv with the right arguments.

Currently I have char***, which I hardly allocate with 3 cycles and then copy from char** to char*** with some not so simple algorithms.

Is there any simple way of splitting array of string to array of arrays of strings? (To me it looks like a trivial task to split array to substrings, but C makes it pretty hard for me)

Also, I know that I could split the input at these special symbols and  then get the arrays between them, but I'm kind of interested how it can be done with splitting the array.

Comment: Look at the `strsep`, `index`, and/or `strchr` functions to assist with this. There's no standard way of doing that kind of splitting in C, but it's pretty straight forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array is nothing more than a contiguous chunk of memory.  You have to handle bounds checks yourself, so you might as well just do that.  In other words, if you have `char **words` where words[0] points to `/bin/ls`, words[1] points to `-l`, words[2] points to `>`, etc., then you already have what you want.  In real code, you would use `char ***commands` and dynamically resize depending on the number of commands, but for the simple case you can do:

```
char **first_command, **second_command, **third_command;
first_command = words;
second_command = words + 3;
third_command = words + 5;
```

Now `first_command` points to the first element of the array `{"/bin/ls", "-l"}` (and hence it points to the array), `second_command` points to the first element of the array `{"f.txt"}`, etc.  Note that in this setup `first_command[2]` is an out-of-array reference, but you need to keep track of the bounds.  In other words, don't go copying the words around, just keep track of where they are.